# How to have a chronological order of items in Android Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a Recylcerview with Cardview and I set the layout by using the code

```
recyclerView = binding.recyclerView;
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Unfortunately, the items are being displayed in an odd way. The first item is in the lower row while the second item is not next to it but above it in the upper row, as you can see in the screenshot. What I want  is to have the items chronologically ordered 1,2,3,4,5 etc until they dont fit anymore into the upper row (next the second row should be filled up). Can you tell me how to do that? I also tried `layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);` but this just vertically mirrored the items.

[image]

**Update**: I still have not figured out how to solve this issue. Here is a screenshot of the items that I insert

[image]
What I mean by chronological order is that they should be displayed in the same order that they are insertet into the arraylist of the RecylerView. So the item with index 0 (@17510) should be the first position at the upper row (red number 1), the item with index 1 (@17511) should be at the second position in the upper row (red number 2) and so on.

Comment: What Is Chronological Order? Chronological order is the arrangement of events based on the time they occurred.

Comment: So you have something to explain.

Comment: @Blackapps: Thanks for your comment. Chronological order is just what you desribed and what I mention in my question. The first inserted item is 1st, the second inserted item is 2nd and so on.

Comment: You did not tell that items were inserted one after another. You only had items. And on the items there is no time label otherwise you had told so.

Comment: @blackapps: Thanks for your comment. Based on that I updated my answer by adding some clarification. Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sort the list based on orientation e.g

```
val orientation = resources.configuration.orientation
    
// Set different sorting orders based on the orientation
if (orientation == android.content.res.Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
     recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2)
     adapter.setData(getSortedDataForPortrait())
} else {
     recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2)
     adapter.setData(getSortedDataForLandscape())
}
```

Below code should mimic the behavior of landscape data. For `getSortedDataForPortrait()` you can just return the original list

```
public static List<String> getSortedDataForLandscape(List<String> data) {

        List<String> firstRow = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> secondRow = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            // Check if index is even or odd
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                firstRow.add(data.get(i));
            } else {
                secondRow.add(data.get(i));
            }
        }

        // Concatenate first and second row lists or first u can add secondRow then firstRow. Upto your preferences.
        List<String> sortedData = new ArrayList<>(firstRow);
        sortedData.addAll(secondRow);

        return sortedData;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad for your answer. Unforunately I get 2 errors `annot resolve method 'setData' in 'RV_Adapter_Level_Selection'` and `Cannot resolve method 'getSortedDataForPortrait' in 'FR_RV_Level_Selection_Menu'`. By the way, I am using Java not Kotlin.

Comment: getSortedDataForPortrait and getSortedDataForLandscape are sample functions where you can do your implementation of sorting based on the orientation

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't understand what you mean by that. I just want to have a chronological order of items. There is no need to sort them. I first insert item 1, then item 2 and so on. Item 1 should be in the first row the first item, item 2 should be in the first row the second items and so on until the line is full  and then the second row should be filled

Comment: Thanks Muhammad for your answer. Any comments to my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: @VanessaFi have updated the code

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and effort. Is there not a more direct way of doing this without an additional method just by adjusting the parameters of the RecylerView Adapter?

Comment: none that I am aware of no,